# How to change a date to a different format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-format

This is a simple question.

How do I transform a date column that comes over as an int.

for example 20190327 convert over to 'MM/dd/yyyy'?
I tried

```
select *,format(Columnname, 'MM/dd/yyyy')  from Table
```

but this didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `select *, cast(cast(ColumnName as char(8)) as datetime) from table`

Comment: Is it an `int`, or is it a `varchar` using the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`?

Comment: Thank you @xabi That did it!!

Comment: This might works too.. select CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),20190327))

Comment: @Larnu it an int

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
declare @i int
select @i = 20190327
select CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),@i))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you in `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(nvarchar(30), cast(cast(Columnname as char(8)) as date), 101) as convertedToDate
FROM Table
```